# What's the simplest and most reliable way to get a string containing nothing but _all unicode emojis_?

Tags: unicode, emoji

Using the command line, a script, etc.

http://www.unicode.org/emoji/

Comment: How would you define “reliable”; do you mean it needs to keep working after the next Unicode Standard update?

Comment: @DanielH Reliable as in _no missing unicode blocks_. It only has to work for the current/latest as of this date, but if possible the current/latest at a future date as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unicode symbols" don't have a clean "plane of Unicode blocks" (see [Wikipedia: Unicode symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols)) and to make matters worse there doesn't exist a definite subset of Unicode symbols that can be considered "proper emojis" (as far as I know).

E.g. the emojis covered by Twitter don't cover all of the Unicode symbols but are dispersed all over the place (though particularly concentrated in some areas over others, such as Miscellaneous Symbols, Emoticons, Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs, Transport and Map Symbols, and Dingbats).

But once you've settled on the Unicode block ranges that you want you can easily print them out, I'll be using the "Emoticons (U+1F600–U+1F64F)" range as an example, since they are "the most universally considered emojis".

```js
var emojis = "";
var code = parseInt("1F600", 16);
while(code <= parseInt("1F64F", 16)) {
  emojis += String.fromCodePoint("0x"+code.toString(16));
  code += 1;
}
console.log(emojis);
```

- [parseInt() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [String.fromCodePoint() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)